# Did an Equity Bake Sale charge Caucasian men more for the same product?

Tags: equality

I came across this picture:

> [image]

Were products sold at different prices to different genders and races during a International Women's Day Equity Bake Sale?

Comment: If true if looks basically like pricing cookies for different groups according to average income for those groups, as a gimmick to raise awareness of income disparities.

Comment: It's a gimmick to get attention and raise money for a cause. It's not an attempt to solve a problem. (Sort of like how pouring a bucket of ice and water over your head doesn't directly help anyone with ALS.)

Comment: I find this question overly general, the answer to "has X every happened anywhere?" is almost always going to be yes.

Comment: While this is a gimmick, does setting up a bake sale or anything like this fall under the jurisdiction of anti-discrimination laws?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the comments noted, this is a form of protest to raise awareness about income inequality.

I did not find the source of this specific flyer, but there are various reports about these types of events.

For example:

- [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/apr/06/the-feminist-cupcake-sale-that-led-us-into-the-darkest-depths-of-gender-inequality) about the backlash from a University of Queensland event in March 2016:

  > The now infamous Gender Pay Gap Bake Sale was an afterthought, a supplementary event to the panel discussions, workshops and stalls to be held throughout feminist week on the University of Queensland campus. We have hosted bake sales before, we just wanted this one to have an educational catch: why not educate students about wage disparity while feeding them sugar?
  >
  > The idea was that each baked good would only cost you the proportion of $1 that you earn comparative to men (or, if you identify as a man, all baked goods would cost you $1). For example, for a woman of colour in the legal profession, a baked good at the stall would only cost you 55 cents.
  >
  > Other university campuses and women’s collectives around the world have done it before – from campuses in the US charging more for white students than black students, to campuses in the UK only giving students the proportion of a cupcake they would earn in real life. This was not a new idea.
- [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/23/jordan-high-school-gender-equality-bake-sale_n_6925692.html) about a High School bake sale:

  > The Young Democrats group at Jordan High School held a gender equality bake sale and charged their fellow students different prices. Boys had to pay $1 for the baked goods, while girls only had to pay 77 cents. This gap in prices reflects the earning power between men and women and the report from the U.S. Census Bureau that women earned 77 cents for every dollar men earned in 2012.

There are a similar set of examples of [Affirmative action bake sales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action_bake_sale), which are hosted to protest an almost opposing issue - against affirmative action.

For example:

- [Daily Bruin](https://web.archive.org/web/20070208102115/http://www.dailybruin.ucla.edu/news/2003/feb/14/democrats-riled-by-race--gende/) reports on a 2003 event:

  > The sale, held on Bruin Walk on Feb. 3, offered cookies at different prices depending on the customer’s race and gender. Black, Latina and American Indian females were charged 25 cents for cookies that cost males of minority descent 50 cents. White females were charged $1, and white males and all Asian Americans were charged $2.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > The intent of the sale, Jones said, was to “bring the issue (of affirmative action) down to everyday terms. We wanted to show how affirmative action is racial division, not racial reconciliation.”